Could not find version of user
I am attempting to install this
sudo pip3 install user upgrade git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint --break-system-packages

But I am getting this following error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement user (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for user

I need help
I have not tried anything because I nothing matches the problem, I was expecting it to work.

The website I got these commands from wasn't accurate. I  am used to video tutorials
